# Linq Contains show all the results in Asp.net Wep api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I got some issues in Asp.net Web Api. here is my Linq statement and used it for autocomplete.

```
(from usr in UserProfile
where usr.MobileNo.Contains('973')
select usr).ToList();
```

Inside my UserProfile table, there are two mobile numbers, 973456789 and 938576478.
it shows all two numbers rather than '973456789'. how can i get only one number start with '973'?

Thanks for any help,
dartfrog

Comment: HAVE YOU TRIED ``STARSWITH()``??

Comment: It's not needed to put everything in uppercase.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/10/13/c.net-little-wonders-searching-strings-with-contains-startswith-endswith-and.aspx)

Comment: None of that answers why the Contains() query doesn't appear to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StartsWith` instead:

```
(from usr in UserProfile
where usr.MobileNo.StartsWith('973')
select usr).ToList();
```

Comment: You might need a ToString() before StartsWith().